Are there currently ways to attack weak implementations of ML-KEM?
I am currently reading about the ML-KEM algorithm. Are there ways to attack weak implementations of it through areas like LWE?

Do you mean such as side channel attacks, or attacks against ML-KEM implementations with weak entropy?

I'm referring to attacks against implementations with weak parameters

Well, the ML-KEM FIPS specifies exactly three parameter sets, none of which are believed to be weak.  Or, are you talking about a Kyber implementation that uses a nonstandard (and weak) set of parameters?

Maybe check out https://bochum-challeng.es/challenges/kyber (ML-KEM "is" Kyber)

yeah I'm talking about an implementation using a weak set of parameters

There was a nice Systematization of Knowledge on implementation challenges for PQC generally. It's very likely the biggest takeaway from this answer is "read section 5 of that paper". As you mention weak parameter sets though, I'll talk about this specifically.
The first thing to say is that weak parameter sets for things like ML-KEM is that they do not seem to be a particularly large concern (they aren't mentioned in the SoK, at least from skimming). They are possible (see the comments of this recent question), but they require making a rather large mistake somewhere, so are perhaps less common than in things like ECC-based crypto.
How ML-KEM (and most practical lattice-based schemes) work is that one starts with a ring $R_q$. The underlying additive group of this ring is just $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ for some pair $(q,n)$. As it is a ring, it has an additional multiplication operation. Typically, one chooses
$$R_q := \mathbb{Z}_q[x] / (f(x))$$
for some monic irreducible polynomial $f$ with $\deg f = n$. Choosing $(f,q)$ wrong can lead to devestating attacks. This happened in the second link I mentioned above. For a more general picture on things, there are several papers with titles like "Weak PLWE" (see for example this) that cover various ways you can go wrong.
That all being said, if you pick $f(x) = x^{2^k}+1$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it is really hard to go wrong here. In other words, a fundamental parameter choice (where one can go wrong) is choosing $R_q$, but there is a single choice essentially everyone uses, so you're really fine unless you mis-copy/mis-implement $f(x)$ to something else (in the linked question, $f(x) = x^{2^k}-1$, which has immediate attacks). Note that there's no real security issue with choosing the wrong value of $q$ (except for if $q$ is too small, though this generally causes correctness issues as well, so is generally easy to detect).
The other ways you can go wrong with parameters are more standard/boring. Security for ML-KEM is (mostly) a function of 4 parameters $(n, r, \sigma, q)$, namely the ring degree $n$, module rank $r$, and error standard deviation $\sigma$, and ciphetext modulus $q$. Choosing any of these too small can lead to issues. But if you choose these based on the parameters from the ML-KEM spec, everything is essentially fine.
There are of course many ways you can plausibly mess up with implementing ML-KEM. But if you follow the specification, and your implementation passes the various test vectors that are available (see for example here), I don't really see how this implementation could suffer from weak parameter choices specifically (of course, it could still have timing side-channels, or many other issues).
